# Push to multidimensional array returns filled array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

My expected output is an array containing a single array with the return values of this algorithm, and 4 other empty arrays. But for some reason I get 5 arrays filled with data, and I'm stumped. You can checkout my code on [repl](https://replit.com/@CullenSharp2/primality-test#index.js) if it helps.

```
const getResults = (Algorithms) => {
  const testCases = [0,1,3,2,10,17,97,51];
  let results = Array(5);
  results.fill([]);

  for(const test of testCases) {
      results[0].push(Algorithms.isPrime(test));
  }

  return(results);
}

getResults(Algorithms);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results.fill([]);
```

is putting the *same* array into each slot of `results` - pushing to one pushes to them all.

Essentially you have:

```
let x = [];
results.fill(x);
// [x, x, x, x, x]
```

and then you are modifying `x`.

You need a different array for each slot, if you do

```
results = Array(5).fill().map(() => []);
```

it will work.

Comment: Can you explain the behavior of Array.fill() a bit more? I understand your solution, but not the initial problem. Or is there something I can read? The MDN docs didn't help me as much as I'd hoped they would.

Comment: Say you have two arrays `x = []` and `y = []`, at a low level, x holds a pointer to a location in memory, and y holds a pointer to a location in memory.  Lets say x is at `0x01` and y is at `0x02`.  If I create a new array `z = [x, y]`, think of it as `z = [0x01, 0x02]`.  If I did `z = [x, x]` it would be `[0x01, 0x01]`.  When you do `results.fill([])`, you are in essence saying "create a new array `0x01`, and put `0x01` in every slot of `results`

Answer (score 1):

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is something you are looking for. Replace those lanes:

```
let results = Array(5)
results.fill([])
```

with:

```js
const res = Array.from({length: 5}, _ => [])

console.log(res)
```